# How to delete lines that contains "{" in first line and "}" in second in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, find-replace

I have this code:

```
.class {
}
```

I want to delete these lines in whole file (it's 6k lines length).
How can i do that?

Comment: I don't know Notepad++, but in Kate you can write `.*\{.*\n.*\}.*`

Comment: this question might be more suitable at http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^{\r\n]+\{\R\}`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Make sure you have checked `Regular expression`

**Explanation:**

```
^           : start of string
  [^{\r\n]+ : 1 or more character that is not left curly brace or line break
  \{        : left curly brace, must be escape as it is a special character
  \R        : any kind of line break
  \}        : right curly brace, must be escape as it is a special character
```